# FramelessWindowHint & WindowStaysOnTopHint won't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want my PyQt5 program to be frameless and always be on top of the screen. When I use the WindowStayOnTopHint it works fine, but when I use it with the FramelessWindowHint it becomes frameless, but does not stay on top of the screen. After doing some research I found [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/45162-How-to-make-a-borderless-window-staying-on-the-top-of-the-system), and it said to try to use setMask, but I could not get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel


class Invisible(QLabel):
 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.__press_pos = None
    self.initUI()

 def initUI(self):
    self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    self.setMask() #This is where I use the setMask function, but it raises an error

    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    self.setText("Drag me...")
    self.setFont(QFont("Times", 50, QFont.Bold))
    self.adjustSize()  
    self.move(QApplication.instance().desktop().screen().rect().center()
              - self.rect().center())

 def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.__press_pos = event.pos()  

 def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.__press_pos = None

 def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.__press_pos:  
        self.move(self.pos() + (event.pos() - self.__press_pos))


 def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Invisible()
    w.show()
    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   sys.exit(main())
```

This code gives me the error:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  setMask(self, QBitmap): not enough arguments
  setMask(self, QRegion): not enough arguments
```

It is asking for more arguments, but when I give it more arguments it says that there are too many arguments. 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you must activate both properties with the operator `|`

```
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

Complete code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QStyle


class Invisible(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__press_pos = QPoint()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setText("Drag me...")
        self.setFont(QFont("Times", 50, QFont.Bold))
        self.adjustSize()
        self.setGeometry(
            QStyle.alignedRect(
                Qt.LeftToRight,
                Qt.AlignCenter,
                self.size(),
                QApplication.instance().desktop().availableGeometry()
                )
            )

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__press_pos = event.pos()  

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__press_pos = QPoint()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.__press_pos.isNull():  
            self.move(self.pos() + (event.pos() - self.__press_pos))

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Invisible()
    w.show()
    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   sys.exit(main())
```

[image]

`setMask()` serves to give a different border to the widget, for example for an [example](https://github.com/CodeHuntersLab/CuriElements) I got the following:

[image]

Comment: I didn't even know that was a thing in python lmao